# flash filereference select event not firing after using browse() and after selecting a file

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload

This is the first time i am working in action script. I have seen a flash programmer working with it. since i know javascript i was able to work in action script.

I am creating a file upload component for my php projects.
Until now i have advanced to show the file dialog box using the FileReference api.
The select event is not firing for me. and i did not get any error.

```
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.events.*
import flash.net.FileReference

var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,sico);
var myButton:Button = new Button();
addChild(myButton); 

myButton.label = "Click Me";

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent)
{
    myButton.label  = "clicked";
    fr.browse();
    trace('clicked');
})

function sico(event:Event):void
{
//var file:FileReference = FileReference(e.target);
myButton.label = "selected";
trace('selected');
//trace("progressHandler: name=" + file.name + " bytesLoaded=" + e.bytesLoaded + " bytesTotal=" + e.bytesTotal);

}
```

The documentation said that file references should be called only during an event like mouse or keyboard.

what am i missing in the above code?

Comment: this should work, but you'll have to check the output for the `trace("selected");` since your click event and select event will happen at the same time so your button's label will not appear to change.

Comment: i created a one-frame fla and copied your code into my fla (removed the new Button() part of the code and added a button from the components panel and named it myButton) and everything worked as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you posted works in Flash CS5 and Flash Player 10.3 which means the problem is not with the code.

Other potential causes of the issue could be:

- The version of Flash Player which you are using is too old. FileReference requires Flash Player 9 or better. Right-click on the Flash Player or use `trace(Capabilities.version)` to see the version number.
- Another part of the application is using a FileReference method (eg:  FileReference.browse(), FileReference.upload(), FileReference.download(), FileReference.load(), FileReference.save()). Flash player 10+ allows only one file operation at  a time.
- If you are using a Mac, then FileReference may only dispatch the SELECT event when the SWF is run inside of a browser.

Comment: another problem i faced today is i used trace(Capabilities.version)... the output window was getting on populated with the version continuously non stop... is this script getting rewinding again and again like a looping movie control. i included the code below myButton.lable line.

Comment: It sounds like the timeline has many frames, which would result in the code being called repeatedly. Ensure that the timeline has only one frame.

Comment: yes. exactly. i was about to mention that. and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

IT was like as stated by user:lukevanin in the comment section of his answer. and me too found the same. The problem was i had many frames in the timeline. since i was new to action script while toggling between F9 i was trying F5 so it created frames and it was looping continuously between that.